# Failed to impersonate domain user via C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to impersonate remote admin user so that i can perform modifications on the files present on remote Linux machine. But i get error message as Access to the path is denied.
However this thing manually i am able to do via putty using command :

```
sudo -S -u wtsnqa rm /path-to-file/
```

Any help is worth appreciable.

My code :

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = "sj1slm612",
    UserName = "userid",
    Password = "password",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 fa:e9:58:24:1b:41:a3:15:63:0d:c0:72:41:5d:51:7a"
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Performing removing files from remote server via impersonation.......

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    using (WindowsIdentity Authorized_user = new WindowsIdentity("wtsnqa"))
    {
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext context = Authorized_user.Impersonate())
        {              

            File.Delete(@"\\sj1slm612\apps\instances\express_13000\configuration\standalone-full.xml");
            File.Delete(@"\\sj1slm612\apps\instances\query_13100\configuration\standalone-full.xml");
            File.Delete(@"\\sj1slm612\apps\instances\wppapi_13200\configuration\standalone-full.xml");
            File.Delete(@"\\sj1slm612\apps\instances\wppgui_13300\configuration\standalone-full.xml");

            Console.WriteLine("All config files removed from sj1slm612");
            Console.ReadLine();
            context.Undo();
        }
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230301/how-to-use-sudo-in-c-sharp .. however, that's not been answered either!

Comment: Make sure that you are running your application with administrator rights

Comment: @USER_NAME : in my code i m trying to impersonate user "wtsnqa" who have the administrator rights.

Comment: @RamanThakur In .net it will not give you error if it fails to impersonate. So u just check whether u r able to impersonate or not.Just print current user name after impersonation to log or some other text file and check what name it is giving to u.

Comment: @RamanThakur If this method fails to give u proper username then make a sample console application who displays the current user name and launch it from ur code with impersonation

Comment: @RamanThakur You can use this code to get the username :string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Comment: @USER_NAME: after applying your cod, It gives me domain\wtsnqa as result

Comment: wtsnqa has all the rights, but still i m getting access is denied to remote server.. Do i need to define impersonation level ?

Comment: No you dont have to define access rights on impersonation. One more thing check before doing code changes. UAC setting of ur windows. Make it default or always ask.